# React-native package Release error while ./gradlew assembleRelease

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-unimodules

> Task :app:packageRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> java.io.IOException: Execution of compression failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project using ./gradlew clean and rebuilding the project...

If doesn't work then, show the error log in details...

Comment: i have already done the cleaning i'll edit the question and will ttach the logs in it